# Did registering a cell calls the awakeFronNib method

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to register a custom collectionView cell

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName:nibName, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier)
```

Did this code calls the awakeFromNib function of the custom cell. The awakeFromNib of the cell is being called and I do not see any other reason for it. I think the answer of my question is no but I just want to be sure.

Comment: No it will only call when it is about to show like in cell for item ,  Did try to put break point check from where it is called ? You can see left panel  to check from where it is actually called

Comment: Return 0 (zero) for `numberOfSections` - that way no cells will be displayed, and you can confirm wether or not `awakeFromNib` is being called as a result of `.register`